# Error occurs when trying to install Homebrew on a Mac for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on my mac with OS 10.8.5 and I am getting an error.

I enter the following into terminal:

```
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

and I get the following error

```
    /Users/marlonmarescia/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this issue. It was a whitespace issue in my application.yml file. I did not format this file correctly as YAML is whitespace sensitive unlike Ruby. Once the file was formatted using tabs or double spaces the rails server worked again.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be connected to the question. What is the `application.yml` file and where is it located?

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you're not using the system ruby, but a ruby via rbenv which you installed via homebrew. Try:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: Hi Diego Basch, I tried this but it didn't work. I just posted the solution I found.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: For me too. Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C1514).

Answer (score 1):

First i tried this:
It was solved by removing line eval

```
  $(rbenv init -)
```

in my ~/.bash_profile.  It didn't work for me.

So I Removed the .rbenv in the /users/ur-username/  path. To remove it you can use this command.

```
 $rm -Rf .rbenv
```

Then go ahead and run the install script. This worked for me.