# Rails -v showing 'No such file or directory' and unlinked libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I've always had trouble with my development environment throwing up errors. I thought I'd got it in a good shape, then I installed RVM so I could use an older version of rails and things went wrong again.

I was running rails 4.x, I tried running rails 3.2.1 via RVM and everything stopped working. I ran 'rvm implode' and removed the RVM stuff from the bash_profile.

When I run rails -v I now get the following message:

```
/Users/andrewallsop/.rbenv/shims/rails: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

When I run brew doctor I get

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/include

Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/locale aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/locale
    /usr/local/share/locale/be
    /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ca
    /usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/cs
    /usr/local/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/da
    /usr/local/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/de
    /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/el
    /usr/local/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/en@boldquot
    /usr/local/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/en@quot
    /usr/local/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/eo
    /usr/local/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/es
    /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/et
    /usr/local/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/fi
    /usr/local/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/fr
    /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/gl
    /usr/local/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/hu
    /usr/local/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/id
    /usr/local/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/it
    /usr/local/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ja
    /usr/local/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/nb
    /usr/local/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/nl
    /usr/local/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/pl
    /usr/local/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/pt
    /usr/local/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR
    /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ro
    /usr/local/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/ru
    /usr/local/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/sk
    /usr/local/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/sv
    /usr/local/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/tr
    /usr/local/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/uk
    /usr/local/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW
    /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/man7

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/yaml.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libyaml.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/yaml-0.1.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libyaml.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    libgpg-error
    libksba
    libtool
    libyaml
```

I just keep making things worse!

Comment: It seems you have rbenv installed. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462949/homebrew-brew-doctor-throwing-up-a-lot-of-errors-how-can-i-fix-them) question can help you.

Comment: Thank you, how do I remove the things home-brew hasn't installed? Is it possible to just start from afresh as I feel this is only one of a number of problems?

Comment: You might want to check this out. Im not sure if it will help your case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595567/2419589